# mongo 3.6.2 failed to start in windows 7 / 10

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am attempting to install mongodb in my windows machine.

When executing the "mongo" command, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Mohamed>mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-01-26T18:51:11.568+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1
:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2018-01-26T18:51:11.568+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ser
ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

When executing the "mongod" command, I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\Mohamed>mongod
```

I removed some output to bypass the imposed limitation

```
create,cache_size=2510M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4)
,config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal
,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0
),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-01-26T18:54:10.321+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-26T18:54:10.322+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access contr
ol is not enabled for the database.
2018-01-26T18:54:10.323+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and wri
te access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-01-26T18:54:10.325+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-26T18:54:10.325+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server
is bound to localhost.
2018-01-26T18:54:10.326+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote syste
ms will be unable to connect to this server.
2018-01-26T18:54:10.328+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the se
rver with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2018-01-26T18:54:10.329+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it
 should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-01-26T18:54:10.330+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all
interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-01-26T18:54:10.330+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with
--bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-01-26T18:54:10.331+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-26T18:54:10.331+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] Hotfix KB2731284 or late
r update is not installed, will zero-out data files.
2018-01-26T18:54:10.332+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-26T18:54:10.333+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: The file sys
tem cache of this machine is configured to be greater than 40% of the total memo
ry. This can lead to increased memory pressure and poor performance.
2018-01-26T18:54:10.334+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] See http://dochub.mongod
b.org/core/wt-windows-system-file-cache
2018-01-26T18:54:10.335+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-26T18:54:10.338+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.
system.version with provided UUID: 70e33b89-7e69-4b86-8309-ff9b06207e41
2018-01-26T18:54:10.520+0100 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibi
lityVersion to 3.6
2018-01-26T18:54:10.531+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.
startup_log with generated UUID: 6728ada5-b42d-443c-823a-1a8ead4eebc2
2018-01-26T18:54:11.584+0100 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to initialize Per
formance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with '
L'objet spécifié n'a pas été trouvé sur l'ordinateur.' for counter '\Memory\Avai
lable Bytes'
2018-01-26T18:54:11.585+0100 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time d
iagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-01-26T18:54:11.590+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections
on port 27017
```

Could you assist me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You're running Windows 7 *and* 10?

Comment: The same error occured in my two PC, one is running windows 10, the other contains windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running **mongod** only, you can run **mongo**. Else, it will throw the above error.

This is what I did:

- Went to -  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.6.1 (in mac) using the terminal
- Run **mongod**
- In a new window/tab run - **mongo**

In your case you have done the above two steps. Just in a new terminal window/tab try running **mongo**.

Hope it helps. Feel free to correct my answer :)

Comment: Dear Mohammed Furquan, many thanks for your assistance. Your proposed solution resolved my problem

Comment: @ MohamedBelhassen Glad to be of help :) You can mark this solution 'to be working' by **accepting** this answer, so that it can be of help to people who stumble across this question.